# Create array of Ids from another already existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to create an array of Ids for each element of an already existing array of unknown size. The tricky part is that I need to have every four elements with the same Id.

For example the new array would be: Assuming the array1 has 20 items, [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5]

I tried doing something with a for loop, but I don't know how I can fill every four elements without overwriting them while iterating.

`for(let i=0; i < itemlist.length; i++) {newArray[i] = i; newArray[i] = i;newArray[i] = i;newArray[i] = i;}`

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: It's the example array I put in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the existing array to a function that generates the id from the index in the existing array

```js
const someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
const yourArray = someArray.map((el, i) => Math.floor(i / 4) + 1);

console.log(yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of one-fourth the size and use `flatMap` to initialize it with four elements of each index.

```js
function generateArray(size){
  return [...Array(size / 4)].flatMap((_,i)=>Array(4).fill(i + 1));
}
console.log(generateArray(20));
```